# Foundation Framework Off-Canvas Menu Not Opening

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, off-canvas-menu

On the following development site, the off-canvas menu isn't firing.

http://pgoutfittersv2.staging.wpengine.com/

The site is using WordPress with the JointsWP Theme.

I'm getting a Console error related to Foundation JS file, but I don't know what it means or it is related.

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at e.value (foundation.min.js?ver=6.0:2)
    at new e (foundation.min.js?ver=6.0:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (foundation.min.js?ver=6.0:1)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at String.<anonymous> (foundation.min.js?ver=6.0:1)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.reflow (foundation.min.js?ver=6.0:1)
    at a.fn.init.a [as foundation] (foundation.min.js?ver=6.0:1)
    at scripts.js:1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me

Comment: I updated Foundation but the theme wasn't referencing the correct files once I did that.  Not sure why that was the case but once I updated the references, it worked.  It should have worked either way since I use the same starting theme on another site without any issues....